# Two-dimensional Array of Objects in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've created a handle subclass called neuron that I'd like to put instances of into an x,y addressable data structure. The objects have interactions with other instances that are 'next' to them in an x,y grid. I created another class called nnet that has a Network property that I wanted to be an NxN array of neurons. Each neuron has a property that is a 1-d array of handles to the other neurons 'next' to it, but I also wanted to have a grid data structure that I could use to identify neuron handles by their x,y. The beginning of the class looks like this, the constructor then goes to identify all the neighbors and attach handles to them.

```
classdef nnet < handle
%NNET structure of interconnected neuron objects


properties
    Network;
end

properties(Constant=true)
    AllPositions = cellstr(['NW'; 'N '; 'NE';  ...
                            'W ';       'E ';  ...
                            'SW'; 'S '; 'SE']);
end

methods
    function obj = nnet(dimX, dimY)
        % Constructor creates and fills a net with X by Y neurons
        % and automatically connects neighbors
        % fill initial array
        for y = 1:dimY
            for x = 1:dimX
                obj.Network(x,y) = neuron(x,y);
            end
        end
```

Matlab doesn't seem to like anything in an n-dim array besides a double, as I get this complaint "Conversion to double from neuron is not possible." Any ideas of a built-in data structure I could use or how to modify and make this work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make Network a cell array before any assignment

```
obj.Network = cell(dimX, dimY);
for y = 1:dimY
    for x = 1:dimX
        obj.Network(x,y) = neuron(x,y);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you start adding elements to the array, create an empty array of `neuron`s.

```
obj.Network = neuron.empty;
```

`empty` is a built-in method of all classes, specifically designed for this.